# C++ Builder, pass argument to onClick button event

Tags: c++, c++builder

I'm using C++Builder to create a GUI.

I dynamically create a button, this button has an `OnClick` event:

```
TButton* exportLongitudinalButton = new TButton(infoGroupBox);
exportLongitudinalButton->Parent = infoGroupBox;
exportLongitudinalButton->Caption = "Export DXF";
exportLongitudinalButton->OnClick = frmConcreteWidth -> onDXFExport;
```

The `onDXFExport` function:

```
void __fastcall TfrmConcreteWidth::onDXFExport(TObject *Sender)
{
   double x = 2.0;
   double y = 4.0;
   dxfFile.drawLongitudinalPlot(x,y);
}
```

Is there a way to pass an argument through the `OnClick` event function?

I would like to have an `onDXFExport` function which would look like this:

```
void __fastcall TfrmConcreteWidth::onDXFExport(TObject *Sender, double x, double y)
```

And call it like this:

```
exportLongitudinalButton->OnClick = frmConcreteWidth -> onDXFExport(this, x, y)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What are the `x` any `y` arguments supposed to be? Perhaps you can get them some other way?

Comment: By the way, this question is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) (the names X and Y are unrelated to your question): You ask for help with a wanted solution, but you never tell us what problem it's supposed to solve. Please always ask about the actual and underlying problem directly instead. If you have a proposed solution you can add that.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the inconvenience. This is juste a example to illustrate the main problem which is: Passing an argument in a onClick event function

Comment: To answer to your first question, it would be possible to retrieve the x and y values ​​with an other way. But it would be more complicated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking for is generally not possible, at least not the way you want.

The `OnClick` event has a very distinct signature that you cannot change. So you will simply have to store your `x`/`y` values somewhere else that `onDXFExport()` can access when needed.

There are many different ways to approach this.

For example, using data members of the `TfrmConcreteWidth` object. Or creating a `struct`/`class` instance to hold the values, and then storing a pointer to that instance in the `TButton::Tag` property. Or deriving a new class from `TButton` and adding your own data members to it.

The closest way to what you are asking for would also be the most complicated way - creating a thunk that directly stores the values and uses inline assembly to call `onDXFExport()` with them, and then you can assign a pointer to that thunk to the event via the use of the [`TMethod`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TMethod) struct. But I would not advise this approach when other approaches are easier and safer to use.

Comment: That is what I thought... Thanks for the pointer and tag method, I hadn't thought of it